# C simple spell check

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char c, word[100], dictionary[100];
    int h,k = 0, l = 0, size, i, right = 11, counter = 0;
    char letter[2] = {0};
    FILE * file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE * dictionaryFile = fopen("american", "r");
    printf("Misspelled words in %s\n", argv[1]);
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){
        counter = 0;
        k = 0;
        while(fscanf(dictionaryFile, "%s", dictionary) != EOF){
            l = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < strlen(word) - counter; i++){
                if(ispunct(word[i])){
                    counter++;
                } 
            } //here
            while(word[k]){
                word[k] = tolower(word[k]);
                k++;
            }
            while(dictionary[l]){
                dictionary[l] = tolower(dictionary[l]);
                l++;
            }
            size = strlen(word) - counter;
            word[size] = '\0';
            right = strcmp(word, dictionary);

            if(right > 0 || right < 0){
                if(word[size - 1] == 's' || word[size - 1] == 'S'){
                    word[size - 1] = '\0';
                    right = strcmp(word, dictionary);
                    if(right > 0 || right < 0){
                    } else {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                counter++;
            }

        }

        if(counter == 0){
            printf("%s\n", word);
        }
    }
    fclose(dictionaryFile);
    fclose(file);
return 1;
}
```

I am taking a single command line argument which is my file with the sentence or words to check. I then check them against a file named 'american' which is a dictionary file. I know there are probably quite a few errors which I can figure out, the problem I am having is a segmentation fault as it gets the the second word of the file. I tested the fscanf and it displayed every word separated by white space and did it correctly but now I am getting a seg fault after the first word. I have just a simple test file that says

```
hello tsting this checkr tests test.
```

I get a seg fault when going from hello to tsting. As I said I can almost guarantee that fixing the seg fault the code will still have errors, at this point I can deal with those errors I just need to get over this seg fault. I had it working without a seg fault right before I added the counter++ in the else statements. I need them and I don't see why they would be causing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the variable `counter` for three conflicting purposes:

- It appears in the terminal condition as the right hand side of a subtraction expression. I believe this, corresponding with the `word[i]` expression below it, is what's causing your crash.
- In the loop immediately before your crash location, you appear to be using it as a punctuation counter.
- Everywhere else, you appear to be using it to count the number of correct matches in your dictionary file.

Because these purposes conflict with each other, `counter` becomes useless for any purpose. You need to think carefully about what you intend to do with `counter`, and make sure you're doing that and only that with it. Why do you need `counter`?

`strlen` returns a `size_t` type, which is unsigned (can't possibly be negative). Supposing `counter` is greater than the return value of `strlen`, you may end up with a huge number rather than a negative number. Thus, your loop may continue well beyond the bounds of your `word` array and into undefined behaviour, which coincidentally causes your crash.

Comment: Thank you, I added a new counter and changed it in the code, it works, I just need to now get the correct output.